# Why is $1 - \lambda_{\max} (\mathrm A^\top \mathrm A) = \lambda_{\min} (\mathrm I - \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A be a non-square matrix. Why is the following equality true?

$$1 - \lambda_{\max} (\mathrm A^\top \mathrm A) = \lambda_{\min} (\mathrm I - \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A)$$

**Attempt:**

Since the eigenvalue of a square matrix $X$, is the reciprocal of the eigenvalue of $X^{-1}$, we have:

$$\lambda_{\max}(\mathrm A^\top \mathrm A) = \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}((\mathrm A^\top \mathrm A)^{-1})}$$

I have the following:

$$\lambda(I - \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A) = 1 - \lambda(\mathrm A^\top \mathrm A)$$

$$\lambda_{\min}(I - \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A) = \frac{1}{\lambda_{\max}((I - \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A)^{-1})}$$

Comment: $\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)=\color{red}{1/}\lambda_{\min}((A^TA)^{-1})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to prove is pretty simple and is true for all square matrices, not just those of the form $A^TA$. $\nu$ is an eigenvalue of $P$ iff $1-\nu$ is an eigenvalue of $I-P$. Thus, any eigenvalue of $I-P$ is of the form $\nu=1-\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P$. Taking the minimum, $\nu_\min=(1-\lambda)_\min=1-\lambda_\max$ since $1-\lambda$ is minimized when $\lambda$ is maximum.

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed obvious looking at it with your logic.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: In particular the fact that $P$ has the form $AA^T$ isn't important...